# Convert base 60 to base 10 in Google Sheets with apps script onEdit // MM:SS.MS to SS.MS

Tags: javascript, function, math, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm with a local auto racing club and I do the timing. Our timing gear outputs the time as **Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds** *(MM:SS.MS)* and would like to input that number but have that cell automatically convert it into the **Seconds.Milliseconds** *(ss.ms)* format so I can easily do some calculations. I would also like to still enter the ss.ms format as well.

**Example:**

Sheet "Time", Columns E,F,G,H, and any row are where I input all the times. So if I stick a time of 1:24.78 in cell E3, I'd like it to convert to 84.78 in the same cell.

I was able to create a function to convert MM:SS.MS to SS.MS but I'd like to have a defined area that when I input the MM:SS.MS in a cell that it will automatically get converted onEdit in the same cell.

```
function MTS() {
  var value   = arguments[0].split(".");
  var time    = value[0].split(":");
  var ms      = parseInt(value[1],10);
  var seconds = parseInt(time[time.length-1],10);
  var minutes = parseInt(time[time.length-2],10);
  var hours   = parseInt(time[time.length-3],10);

  var output = (minutes * 60) + seconds + '.' + ms;

  return output;

};
```

Here is a link to the Google spreadsheet in question:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoFFjAyGmvrydGQ5VVd6cXJWTjJMZkhsRkc3bFplOXc&usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like it might be possible by writing an add-on that uses an edit event handler: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I'm not inclined enough to figure out how to combine the two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Call `MTS(e)` within `onEdit` like the code is now. Use the existing spreadsheet object that gets passed (represented by `e`) to set the value back into the same range that was edited after the conversion. `e.range.setValue(output);`

Comment: Thanks Bryan P for taking a look at my sample spreadsheet and messing around with the scrip! I’m fairly new to GAS and this one thing was bugging me for days.

Comment: Quick question, How can I specify a specific sheet that I want this to work with? I know about getSheetByName(SheetName) but not sure where to place it. I'll mess around to see if I can figure it out as well.

Comment: you'll have to add that in as another condition in the IF statement I provided. `&& e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Sheet 1'`

Comment: Awesome, thanks again. I knew something had to go in the IF statement but was sure exactly hot to put it. I'm also starting to understand how the IF statement you created works.

Answer (score 0):

For people who may stumble upon this, below is what **[Bryan P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480465/bryan-p)** came up with to solve my exact question I posted.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if ( e.range.getValue() && 
       /^(5|6|7|8)$/.test(e.range.columnStart) && 
       e.range.columnStart == e.range.columnEnd && 
       e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd ) {

         MinutesToSeconds(e);    
  }
};


function MinutesToSeconds(e) {

  var value   = e.range.getValue().split(".");
  var time    = value[0].split(":");
  var ms      = parseInt(value[1],10);
  var seconds = parseInt(time[time.length-1],10);
  var minutes = parseInt(time[time.length-2],10);
  var output = (minutes * 60) + seconds + '.' + ms;

  e.range.setValue(output);

  return;
};
```

This only converts up to the minute, you can add another variable for "hours" in the MinutesToSeconds() function. Then change the math in the variable "output".

```
var hours   = parseInt(time[time.length-3],10);
```

If anyone knows how to do the math for the hours even if there is no data for hours feel free to post.

Because if I do

```
var output = (hours * 60) * (minutes * 60) + seconds + '.' + ms;
```

And don't have and data in "hours" it gives a NaN error.